# Contar sequencias de zeros baseado em outra coluna

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estou tentando fazer uma rotina onde eu possa contar os registros zero em sequencia de uma coluna de frutas.
Funciona assim: Cada linha uma fruta é mostrada e a coluna C representa se a fruta foi utilizada ou nao, sendo 1 representando que foi usada e zero representando que aquela determinada fruta nao foi utilizada.
Preciso contar as vezes em que aquela fruta nao foi usada em sequencia, pra saber a quanto tempo ela nao é utilizada.
O resultado que eu espero está representado na coluna 'Esperado' do DataFrame (df):

```
 B       C  Esperado
pera     0  1
uva      1  0 
banana   0  1 
laranja  0  1 
uva      1  0 
uva      1  0 
banana   1  0 
laranja  0  1 
uva      0  1 
uva      0  2 
uva      1  0 
laranja  0  1 
laranja  0  2 
laranja  0  3 
laranja  0  4
```

Eu ja consegui resolver fazendo assim:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['B'] == 'uva'
df2['Esperado'] = np.where(df2['C'] == 0, df2.groupby( (df2['C'] != df2['C'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1,0)
```

Porem, como são muitas frutas, pensei em algo do tipo:

```
for fruta in df['B'].unique():
  df2 = df.loc[df['B'] == fruta
  df2['Esperado'] = np.where(df2['C'] == 0, df2.groupby( (df2['C'] != df2['C'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1,0)
  df['Esperado'] = df2['Esperado]
```

o problema que o código acima muda o tamanho do vetor original (Fica menor ja que eu filtrei o df) e não sei como posso ir colocando esse array menor no df por partes.

Estou tentando assim:

```
for fruta  in df['B'].unique():
df['Esperado'] = np.where(
    (df['C'] == 0) & (df[df['B'] == fruta]), 
    df.groupby( [(df['B']==fruta),(df['C'] != df['C'].shift()).cumsum()]).cumcount() + 1,0)
```

Quando executo isso nao funciona e o computador trava

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Consegue colocar os dados armazenados no dataframe em formato CSV na pergunta? Desta forma fica mais fácil de reproduzir seu problema. Da uma lida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de como você cria um exemplo mínimo e executável.

Comment: Alterei a forma de mostrar a tabela, ajuda assim? Não sei como colocar em csv

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Para que seja possível contar sequências de zeros baseado em outra coluna:

Use o método `apply` para cada fruta que desejar, assim como mostro abaixo:

```
# Crie uma função para contar os zeros
def contar_zeros_seguidos(group):
    group['Esperado'] = np.where(
        group['C'] == 0,
        group.groupby((group['C'] != group['C'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1,
        0
    )
    return group

# Execute a função
df = df.groupby('B').apply(contar_zeros_seguidos)
```

Esta função fará com que cada grupo de frutas (referente à **coluna B**) retorne como resposta um dataframe, com a coluna 'Esperada', e preenchida com o resultado de cada fruta.

Comment: Brother, funcionou bem demais! Muito Obrigado, deus lhe abençoe.

Comment: Nesse exemplo, como eu saberia dentro da função em qual 'B' eu estou calculando no momento? Digo, se eu quisesse usar o nome da fruta que eu estou contando pra referenciar uma coluna, como eu faria?